# Is it possible to use an Azure User Assigned Managed Identity to connect to an Azure SQL DB with an r2dbc driver?

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-mssql

I'd like to connect to an Azure SQL DB from a Spring Boot webflux (reactive) application deployed as an Azure Container App. Is it possible to connect to the Azure SQL DB using passwordless authentication? In particular, is it possible to do using a User Assigned Managed Identity?

I've partially reviewed https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql driver source code for clues, but found none.